# If $\tan x = -1$, simplify $\tan(\pi/3+x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\tan x = -1$, simplify $\tan(\pi/3+x)$.

Progress so far:

[image]

See new expression in top right. What do I do to rationalize this fraction's denominator? Do I multiply the fraction by 1+sqrt3/1+sqrt3?

---

EDIT:

Okay, I'm a little confused as to what my 'final answer' will be.. mfl's answer seems as if it should be simplified. If so, which answer below is correct? Or is mfl's answer to be left as is?
[image]

Comment: Isn't $\tan(x) = -1$? If so, just plug it into you equation before you tried to rationalize the denominator.

Comment: You plugged in $\tan(x)=-1$ into the numerator, but you seem to have forgotten to do so in the denominator.

Comment: @dustin I did so, and got the above (see edit). How do i rationalize the denominator from here?

Comment: It is a multiplication of $-1$, correct? The way you noted it looks like subtraction.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that. My own mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right way, but you have forgotten to substitute $\tan x=1$ in all places where it appears.

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+x)=\frac{\tan\frac{\pi}{3}+\tan x}{1-\tan\frac{\pi}{3}\tan x}\underbrace{=}_{\tan x=-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{1+\sqrt{3}}\\=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{1+\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}-1}=\frac{(\sqrt{3}-1)^2}{3-1}=\frac{(\sqrt{3}-1)^2}{2}.$$

Comment: .. which can be simplified further to $2 - \sqrt{3}$, fwiw.

Comment: One question- why did you multiply the fraction by sqrt3 minus 1? Why not 1 + sqrt 3??

Comment: When you want to rationalize you make use of the formula $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2.$ In this way if $a$ is a square root then it dissapears when you get $a^2.$ That is $(\sqrt{3}-1)(\sqrt{3}+1)=(\sqrt{3})^2-1^1=3-1=2.$ Note that $(\sqrt{3}+1)(\sqrt{3}+1)=(\sqrt{3})^2+2\sqrt{3}+1^1=3+1+2\sqrt{3}=4+2\sqrt{3},$ and the square root continues to be there.

Comment: @SimonS How did you simplify that solution to get 2-sqrt3? Do you mind showing me?

Comment: Notice that $(\sqrt{3} - 1)^2 = \sqrt{3}^2 - 2\cdot 1 \cdot \sqrt{3} + 1^2 = 3 - 2\sqrt{3} + 1 = 2(2 - \sqrt{3})$

Comment: @SimonS   Okay, I'm following until the last expression.. How did you get from 3-2sqrt3+1 to 2(2-sqrt3)? How did you factor out that 2, and why is it not in your final answer?

Comment: Note that $3-2\sqrt{3}+1=4-2\sqrt{3}=2(2-\sqrt{3}).$

Comment: ...and it's not in the final answer because look at what mfl's expression is above. It isn't $(\sqrt{3}-1)^2$, rather it's ...

Comment: @SimonS Okay, that makes sense. So my final simplified answer will be 2(2-sqrt3), correct?

Comment: No. Look again at mfl's expression.

Comment: @SimonS  Yes, I realize that is the correct answer, but you commented that it could be simplified further to 2-sqrt3. Is your simplified version in your first comment the "final answer"? Sorry for the bombardment of questions.

Comment: What I'm saying is 

$$(\sqrt{3} - 1)^2 = 2(2 - \sqrt{3}) \ \Longrightarrow \ \frac{(\sqrt{3} - 1)^2}{2} = 2 - \sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan x=-1$, your denominator should be $1+\sqrt{3}$.